# Set LD_BIND_NOW variable to solve TNS Linux Error: 29: Illegal seek error

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, bash

I faced issue while starting TNS Listener for my Oracle XE DB on my Linux box using bash shell:

```
LSNRCTL> start
Starting /oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12537: TNS:connection closed
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00507: Connection closed
   Linux Error: 29: Illegal seek
LSNRCTL> exit
```

I tried a lot with different solutions given in internet and finally the issue got solved after referring to post - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23308/linux-error-29-illegal-seek-in-lsnrctl-for-linux-version-11-2

The solution for my case is:

```
export LD_BIND_NOW=1
```

I have installed Oracle XE DB in multiple Linux boxes but I faced this issue with only 1 box. What is this variable and how it solves Illegal seek issue?

My Linux box details are:

```
bash-4.1$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 2.6.39-100.5.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 6 20:26:00 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: All those Linux boxes were with the same kernel version and hardware?

Comment: Yes, this worked for me also!

Answer (score 1):

> Controlling the operation of the dynamic loader
>
> There are a range of environment variables that the dynamic loader
>   will respond to. Most of these are more use to ldd than they are to
>   the average user, and can most conveniently be set by running ldd with
>   various switches. They include
>
> LD_BIND_NOW --- normally, functions are not `looked up' in libraries
>   until they are called. Setting this flag causes all the lookups to
>   happen when the library is loaded, giving a slower startup time. It's
>   useful when you want to test a program to make sure that everything is
>   linked.

**In simple terms - If LD_BIND_NOW variable is set to 1, in C, C++ it causes lazy load, of libraries (i.e load libraries when required) or when its used - instead of loading during startup**

**If the software operates in mixed mode, this is set too.**

May be in your case, its a start up issue and this library was never used...!

Answer (score 1):

Today I experienced the same issue. The problem appears to be a bug inside the binary `tnslsnr` executable.

The solution I had was to change the hostname to an IP address in the listener.ora situated in `/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora`

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Tweaking the file `/etc/hosts` and overriding the localhost statement, like described in other answers, does not work.

I don't know if using IP addresses instead of hostname is recommended but, for me, it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Include in `/etc/hosts` file the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```